# Datasource Metrics for Postgres DB are not available at /q/metrics endpoint [QUARKUS]

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-reactive

Quarkus App - Rest service to fetch data from Postgres DB

Quarkus version : 2.9.0.Final

Postgres Extension - **quarkus-reactive-pg-client**

Micrometer Extension - **quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus**

After adding the above extensions , the postgres db metrics are not available at **/q/metrics** endpoint.

**How to get the pg datasource metrics while using reactive pg drivers**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for metrics in the reactive client is not ready yet. It's predicted to become available on Quarkus 2.16.

Once is done, you need to enable the DB metrics by setting this property:

```
quarkus.datasource.metrics.enabled=true
```

As explained here: https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#datasource-metrics

Comment: this is to enable health endpoint for the datasource , it indicates the health of the db like if its UP/DOWN , it does not expose db metrics on /q/metrics endpoint .

Comment: Fixed my answer... Sorry, copied the wrong property.

Comment: yes have tried this configuration and it works if ur using a jdbc driver to interact with db. In my case the configuration did not work as I am using reactive postgres driver to interact with db.

Comment: Fixed my answer... That functionality will become available on Quarkus 2.16.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for the update